# unsupported operand types(s) for += 'float' and 'pygame.surface'

Tags: python, pygame

**Here is the main code**

```
import pygame
from player import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer")

gravity=-0.5

black = (0,0,0)
blue = (50,60,200)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


player=Player(400,0)

gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):

            gameLoop = False

        window.fill(blue)
        player.update(gravity)
        player.update(window)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

**Here is the second file**

```
import pygame

class Player:

    def __init__(self,x,y):

        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=32
        self.height=32
        self.velocity=0

    def update(self, gravity):
        self.velocity += gravity
        self.y -= self.velocity

    def render(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,0,0),(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))
```

I am following along a tutorial series and the teacher had put this exact code in. I am trying to reverse engineer using this code to learn more about how to make platformers, but am unable to get this code to work.. Any ideas?

**The error is in this code:**

```
def update(self, gravity):
        self.velocity += gravity
        self.y -= self.velocity
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Though at a guess it is because the second call to *update* should be a call to *render* instead.

Comment: @JGreenwell - The error message is in the question title: "unsupported operand types(s) for += 'float' and 'pygame.surface'". And yes, that `player.update(window)` call looks like it should be `player.render(window)` instead.

Comment: Does it work now? :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already by *@JGreenwel* and *@rmunn* the problem is that **you call your `.render()` method** of your `player` object ***two times*** in your main program loop **, but pass** at the same time ***two different objects*** (`gravity` and `window`) **to it**:

```
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # ... some code ...
        player.update(gravity) #1. call
        player.update(window) #2. call

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The result is a `TypeError`, because **the `.render()` method needs numbers** and not `pygame.surface` instances **to work as expected**.

To solve this problem you need to **change the second method call to** `player.`**`render`**`(window)`:

```
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # ... some code ...
        player.update(gravity) #1. update some attributes
        player.render(window) #2. blit player onto the screen

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Now some `player` attributes (e.g. `self.velocity` or `self.y`) get an updated by the first method call and the second one draws the object -- depending on tis attributes -- onto the screen.

Comment: Please don't overdo it **with the _formatting_** :-)